# Ajax Form and Django integration post errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to store data from a form into my Database, I am using Django-Python for the backend.

Here is my HTML form

```
<form>
<center>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:white;">
                <p>First name:<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:white;">
                <p><input type="text" id="firstname"><br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:white;">
                 <p>Last name:<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:white;">
                <p><input type="text" id="lastname"><br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:white;">
                <p>Email ID:<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:white;">
                <p><input type="text" id="email"><br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:white;">
                <p>Delivery Address:<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:white;">
                <p><input type="text" id="address"><br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5" style="background-color:white;">
                <p>Contact Number:<br></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:white;">
                <p><input type="number" id="number"><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
            <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
                <p>"Payment mode:- Cash On Delivery,</p>
                <p>All payment have to be done to the delivery boy by cash."</p><br>
            <center> 
                <button onclick = "submitform()" class="button" style="background-color:black;color:#ffcb04;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;border-radius: 10px">Submit</button>
            </center>
</form>
```

This is my javascript/Jquery/Ajax

```
function submitform(){
firstname = $("#firstname").val()
lastname = $("#lastname").val()
email = $("#email").val()
address = $("#address").val()
number = $("#number").val()
string = {
    'firstname' :firstname,
    'lastname' : lastname,
    'email' : email,
    'address' : address,
    'number' : number
}
json_string = JSON.stringify(string);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '/orders/store-order-details/',
        data: json_string,
        success: function(data) {
                window.location.href = "/confirmation/";
                }
});
}
```

This is my Django views.py

```
def store_order_details(request):
received_json_data = json.loads(request.body)
customer_obj = Customer(first_name=received_json_data['first_name'], last_name=received_json_data['last_name'],
                    email_ID=received_json_data['email_id'], contact_number=received_json_data['number'],
                    address=received_json_data['address'])
print(customer_obj)
customer_obj.save()
print(received_json_data['data'])
return Response(status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I am not able to figure out the bug in this as I feel this is alright at the superficial level.

The problem is that the data is not getting stored in the database. I am not sure if the data is posted by the Ajax. I feel the Python code in the view is fine. However I doubt if json.loads will work.

I get this error in the terminal

"POST /orders/store-order-details/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2274

When I test my view by using URL parameters

I get this error

the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

All form inputs are alphanumeric

Comment: you didn't mention the exact error

Comment: what bug? you don't mention what's the problem

Comment: The problem is that the data is not getting stored in the database. I am not sure if the data is posted by the Ajax. I feel the Python code in the view is fine. However I doubt if json.loads will work.

Comment: Just sending plain characters, alphanumeric

Comment: Changed that. Still it is giving the error

Comment: Do you think my ajax code right?

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with any of your code. The console is showing you have a 403 response, which is a Forbidden code; this is because Django protects POST requests from cross-site scripting attacks.

See [the CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/) for what to do.